# Play custom filter JSON error

Tags: scala, playframework, silhouette

I am making a REST API in [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Home) with help of [Silhouette](http://silhouette.mohiva.com/docs) for authentication(JWT).

I need to add some headers to every secured response(only when user is logged). So I thought to use a [filter](http://silhouette.mohiva.com/docs/filters) to add them. But I get this strange error that I couldn't figure out:

> For request 'POST /signIn' [Invalid Json: No content to map due to
>   end-of-input at [Source:
>   akka.util.ByteIterator$ByteArrayIterator$$anon$1@7bf4f7c1; line: 1,
>   column: 0]]

My filter:

```
class SecuredFilter @Inject() (silhouette: Silhouette[DefaultEnv])(implicit val mat: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Filter {
    def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {

        val action = silhouette.UserAwareAction.async { userAwareReq =>
            userAwareReq.identity match {
                case None => nextFilter(requestHeader)
                case Some(identity) =>
                    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
                        result.withHeaders( /* add headers*/ )
                    }
            }
        }               
        action(requestHeader).run
    }
}
```

Filters class:

```
class Filters @Inject() (csrfFilter: CSRFFilter, securityHeadersFilter: SecurityHeadersFilter, 
        securedFilter: SecuredFilter) extends HttpFilters {

  override def filters: Seq[EssentialFilter] = Seq(csrfFilter, securityHeadersFilter, securedFilter)

}
```

Comment: Is your filter in the default package? If not, you have to inform Play of the package - [see this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaHttpFilters#Using-filters) (in case you did not read it already).

Comment: Filter is triggered, I get no error when it's not included...

Comment: Did you solved the prolem?

Comment: @AndrewLuca kinda... I used a different approach, see here: https://github.com/olivebh/play-silhouette-ratelimiting/blob/master/app/utils/ratelimiting/RateLimiting.scala#L41

Answer (score 2):

Passed almost one year, but since I've faced same problem and spent 2 days on finding solution to that issue, I feel in duty to show it.
The issue here relates to parsing the body of request more than 1 time: one in filter and second time in Controller. Thus, the solution is to give a parser(explicitly) that don't parse the body content: **play.api.mvc.BodyParsers.parse.empty**.

The filter will look like:

```
class SecuredFilter @Inject() (silhouette: Silhouette[DefaultEnv])(implicit val mat: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Filter {
    def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {

        val action = silhouette.UserAwareAction.async(BodyParsers.parse.empty) { userAwareReq =>
            userAwareReq.identity match {
                case None => nextFilter(requestHeader)
                case Some(identity) =>
                    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
                        result.withHeaders( /* add headers*/ )
                    }
            }
        }               
        action(requestHeader).run
    }
}
```

Hope this will save someone's time.